# Swift Navigationbar and view background color

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create an app with where the background color for the UINavigationBar and UIView are the same.

This is what I did:

- Created customUINavigationBar (inherits from UINavigationBar)
- Created customUIView (inherits from UIView)

Then I added the following code to `customUINavigationBar`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.backgroundColor = Colors.turquoise
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AppleGothic", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.titleTextAttributes = attributes

    for parent in self.subviews {
        for child in parent.subviews {
            if child is UIImageView {
                child.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding `self.barTintColor = Colors.turquoise` and `self.tintColor = Colors.turquoise` to the init function, but this wouldn't change the result.

In my `customUIView` class, I have the following code:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.backgroundColor = Colors.turquoise
}
```

`Colors.turquoise` comes from a custom class containing this line of code:

```
static var turquoise = UIColor(red: 132/255, green: 217/255, blue: 217/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

The result of the above code is shown in the screenshot. As you can see, there's a small difference in colors between the navigation bar and the view. How can I get the same colors without any difference for the navigation bar and the view?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Result of above code]

Comment: Did you try self.translucent = false; self.opaque = true in your required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) method?

Comment: Just tried, with your suggestion (also changing translucent to true) gives a darker navigation bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float values for your color "132.f/255.f green:217.f/255.f blue:217.f/255.f"

I created the same subclass of UINavigationBar in objective-c:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.translucent = NO;
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:132.f/255.f green:217.f/255.f blue:217.f/255.f alpha:1.0];
    }
    return  self;
}
```

And it works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I change the UIColor to use for example 217.f/255.f, I get the "value of type 'Int' has no member 'f'" error.

Comment: Just use it this way UIColor (red: 132.0/255.0, green: 217.0/255.0, blue: 217.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: sorry haven't had the time to try it earlier, but it worked! Thanks for your help.